# Receive VoIP call via Google Voice => IPKall => Sip2Sip => Android?

Tags: voip, sip

I'm trying to setup VoIP calling to/from my Android phone.

I'm currently working on the incoming call part of the equation. To try to isolate the various parts, I started with the "IPKall => Sip2Sip" part of the equation, and confirmed that calling the IPKall phone number results in a recorded incoming call on Sip2Sip.

I then added "Sip2Sip" as a SIP provider on my Android phone, and found that dialing the IPKall number results in the Android phone ringing.

However, *and this is where I need help*, even though it is ringing, when I go to answer the call, I am unable to pick up the call. Any ideas on how to fix this?

<sup>Version of Android is 2.3 Gingerbread.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/), released under [GNU GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), also available from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua) and save yourself a lot of trouble.

> sipdroid is a free SIP/VoIP client for Android.

As for a SIP provider, [Sipgate](http://www.sipgate.com/) for example gives good results for both outgoing and incoming calls.

**From version 2.0**

> For Google™ Voice users, Sipdroid can now create a new, free PBXes account that is automatically linked to an existing Google™ Voice account. The new feature requires Android 2.0, or above, and Google's app connected to your Voice account.

Download the current version [Sipdroid-2.7.apk](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/downloads/detail?name=Sipdroid-2.7.apk&can=2&q=) available since May 21, 2012.

SHA1 Checksum:   a261e14ba592c8a86e8d0f07374108c6d768e1d4

[image]

Comment: As of the time of this comment, sipgate seems to be closing its doors completely on Oct. 31, 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Grove IP or Talkatone.

**Why**

Because it transparently uses your Google Voice account. You don't have to bother with any SIP provider or configuring any other setting. Just give it your Google voice user name and password(Two factor authentication recommended) and you're good to go.

Grove IP comes with [lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvoip&hl=en) and [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gvoip&hl=en) version. Paid version is $.499 atm.

[Talkatone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.talkatone.android&hl=en) comes with free and subscription based model.

However both worlds flawlessly on free version with ad support.